# String function optimisation?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and i just wrote a function to tell me if certain characters in a string repeat or not:

```
bool repeats(string s)
{
    int len = s.size(), c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < len; k++){
            if(i != k && s[i] == s[k]){
                c++;
            }    
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

...but i can't help but think it's a bit congested for what it's supposed to do. Is there any way i could write such a function in less lines?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve in some more detail.  If you have an example case(s), add that as well.  To me it is unclear what problem you need to solve

Comment: As currently formulated, it seems like OP wants to implement this function in less lines. But in that case the question might be more appropriate on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if your code already works and you're looking to improve it. However, that depends whether your goal is actually to improve it or really just to make it shorter (see above). Things like replacing the inner loop with `std::count` fall directly into advice you might find there, but other advice might end up leading to _more_ lines.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way i could write such a function in less lines?

With std, you might do:

```
bool repeats(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::/*unordered_*/set<char>{s.begin(), s.end()}.size() != s.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>

bool repeats(std::string s){
    for (auto c : s){
         if(std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c) - 1)
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If `it` is an element of `s`, won't `std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), it)` always be at least `1` and this is basically a weird way of writing `return s.size() != 0;`?

Comment: This is (unnecessarily) quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not looking for repeated substrings :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

std::set<char> ignore_characters{ ' ', '\n' };

bool has_repeated_characters(const std::string& input)
{
    // std::set<char> is a collection of unique characters
    std::set<char> seen_characters{};

    // loop over all characters in the input string
    for (const auto& c : input)
    {
        // skip characters to ignore, like spaces
        if (ignore_characters.find(c) == ignore_characters.end())
        {
            // check if the set contains the character, in C++20 : seen_characters.contains(c)
            // and maybe you need to do something with "std::tolower()" here too
            if (seen_characters.find(c) != seen_characters.end())
            {
                return true;
            }

            // add the character to the set, we've now seen it
            seen_characters.insert(c);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void show_has_repeated_characters(const std::string& input)
{
    std::cout << "'" << input << "' ";

    if (has_repeated_characters(input))
    {
        std::cout << "has repeated characters\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "doesn't have repeated characters\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    show_has_repeated_characters("Hello world");
    show_has_repeated_characters("The fast boy"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str;
... fill your string here...

int counts[256]={0};
for(auto s:str)
    counts[(unsigned char)s]++;
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    if(counts[i]>1) return true;
return false;
```

- 6 lines instead of 9
- O(n+256) instead of O(n^2)

Answer (score -2):

**This is your new compact function :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int occurrences(string s, char c) {
    return count(s.begin(), s.end(), c); }

int main() {
    //occurrences count how many times char is repetated. 
    //any number other than 0 is considered true.
    
    occurrences("Hello World!",'x')?cout<<"repeats!":cout<<"no repeats!";
    
    //It is equal write
    //
    //  if(occurrences("Hello World!",'x'))
    //      cout<<"repeats!";
    //  else 
    //      cout<<"no repeats!";
    //So to count the occurrences
    //
    //  int count = occurrences("Hello World!",'x'); 
}
```